# Make the "Select next tag Badge" info text centered

Tags: bug, design, badge-progress

So here it is, the current *Select your next badge* dialog:

[image: Non centered text]

The text *"showing top 100 of n available badges; please use the search box to find a specific badge"* doesn't seem to be good positioned.

Can we center it? Or maybe even better, reduce the items to 99 and give some margin to the top?